# how to do partitions on subdirectories in hive

Tags: hadoop, hive

I have directory structure like below in my hadoop,

```
`/hadoop/maindirec/subdirect1/file1
 /hadoop/maindirec/subdirect1/file2
 /hadoop/maindirec/subdirect2/file1 
 /hadoop/maindirec/subdirect2/file2
 /hadoop/maindirec/subdirect3/file1 
 /hadoop/maindirec/subdirect3/file2
 /hadoop/maindirec/subdirect4/file1    
 /hadoop/maindirec/subdirect4/file2
 /hadoop/maindirec/subdirect5/file1
 /hadoop/maindirec/subdirect5/file2`
```

Now i want to create hive table with orc format as maindirec and subdirect1-5 as partiations.
could anyone please let me know how it can be done.
Thanks in advance.

**so far**

`create external table temp(name string,id int) partitioned by(subd string)
row format delimited
fields terminated by '\t'
stored as orc location '/hadoop/maindirec'
tblproperties("orc.compress"="SNAPPY","skip.header.line.count"="4");`


`alter table temp add partition(subd='subdirect1') location '/hadoop/maindirec/subdirect1' partition(subd='subdirect2') location '/hadoop/maindirec/subdirect2' partition(subd='subdirect3') location
'/hadoop/maindirec/subdirect3' partition(subd='subdirect4') location
'/hadoop/maindirec/subdirect4' partition(subd='subdirect5') location '/hadoop/maindirec/subdirect5';`

**Input**
`select * from temp;`
**Output**
`Failed with exception java.io.IOException:java.lang.RuntimeException: serious problem`

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code:(change and add column names as per your need)

> CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE temp_table ( col1 int,col2 int) PARTITIONED BY ( subd string) 
>   ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
>   LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' 
>   STORED AS ORC 
>   LOCATION '/hadoop/maindirec';
>
> ALTER TABLE temp_table ADD PARTITION (subd='subdirect1') LOCATION
>   '/hadoop/maindirec/subdirect1/files1-100'
>                              PARTITION (subd='subdirect2') LOCATION '/hadoop/maindirec/subdirect2/files1-100'
>                              PARTITION (subd='subdirect3') LOCATION '/hadoop/maindirec/subdirect3/files1-100'
>                              PARTITION (subd='subdirect4') LOCATION '/hadoop/maindirec/subdirect4/files1-100'
>                              PARTITION (subd='subdirect5') LOCATION '/hadoop/maindirec/subdirect5/files1-100';

Comment: thank you for your quick response.
In the above table creation you are creating external table so how it can be done.
can the files be compressed or can we see any changes in data because its external should data be changed after creating table as ORC.

Comment: External table is done for pointing your data path for that table.Dropping of table won't delete your data if its external.and yes,it can be compressed.There is no effect on data for table being external.

Comment: i have multiple files under subdirectory. how to load all at a time.

Comment: hi drago,
under subdirectory files1-100 means number of files could be 1 to 100.in that case how to provide location for all 100 files?