# counting hours from date and time

Tags: hive

**I have created table like below,**

create table sample(date string,time string,product string);

**records:**

2014-12-01,00:00:00,dove
2014-12-01,00:23:45,yardely
2014-12-01,01:00:00,yardely

**my question is:** I want to count the products group by hour.

**Note:** sale starting time is at 2014-12-01,00:00:00 and this will be the first hour.

**expected output like below,**

1h,2
2h,1

as the date & time are loaded string im not able to extract hour.

Please give me an idea how it can be done.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Concatenate date and time together and use Hive's built-in `HOUR()` function to retrieve hour from the timestamp.

**Query**:

```
select HOUR(concat(date,' ', time)),
    count(*)
from staging_table
group by HOUR(concat(date,' ', time));
```

**Output**:

```
00,2
01,1
```

For your expected output, use a `CASE` statement to convert hour 00 to 1, 01 to 2 etc ...

Comment: my date should be start with 2014-12-01 00:00:00
if query encounters date like 2014-12-02 00:00:00 then it should be 24th hour as we are counting from 0th hour. will it be possible with the above query.

Comment: please have a look at this 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33014111/how-to-do-partitions-on-subdirectories-in-hive/33069047?noredirect=1#comment53957039_33069047