# FileNotFoundException in hive UDF

Tags: java, hive, udf

my UDF:

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

import org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.UDF;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable;

public class HoursDiff extends UDF {

    //private  = new Text();

    public IntWritable evaluate(String date,String time)
    {
        String dateStart = "2014-12-01 00:00:00"; 
        String currentdate=date+" "+time;
        SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
        Date d1 = null;
        Date d2 = null;
        try
        {
            d1 = format.parse(dateStart);
            d2 = format.parse(currentdate);
            long diff = d2.getTime() - d1.getTime();
            long diffHours = diff / (3600000) % 24;
            long diffDays = diff / (86400000);
            int hours=(int)(diffDays*24+diffHours);
            IntWritable hour=new IntWritable(hours);
            return hour;
        }
        catch (Exception e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

I exported into */home/hadoop/mapreduce/HoursDiff.jar*

I opened the hive shell:

```
add jar /home/hadoop/mapreduce/HoursDiff.jar;
create temporary function hoursdiff as HoursDiff;
```

when I am trying to execute the following command, im getting `FileNotFoundException`:

```
select hoursdiff(date,time) as hours from date_test;
```

**STACK TRACE**

```
create temporary function hoursdiff as 'HoursDiff';
OK
Time taken: 0.009 seconds
hive> select hoursdiff(date,time) as hours from date_test;
Total jobs = 1
Launching Job 1 out of 1
Number of reduce tasks is set to 0 since there's no reduce operator
15/10/11 15:17:03 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
Execution log at: /tmp/hadoop/hadoop_20151011151616_2c15561f-7cd2-4012-8bd2-b7dfcf488432.log
java.io.FileNotFoundException: File does not exist: hdfs://172.16.253.17:54310/home/hadoop/mapreduce/HoursDiff.jar
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem$18.doCall(DistributedFileSystem.java:1122)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem$18.doCall(DistributedFileSystem.java:1114)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystemLinkResolver.resolve(FileSystemLinkResolver.java:81)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.getFileStatus(DistributedFileSystem.java:1114)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.filecache.ClientDistributedCacheManager.getFileStatus(ClientDistributedCacheManager.java:288)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.filecache.ClientDistributedCacheManager.getFileStatus(ClientDistributedCacheManager.java:224)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.filecache.ClientDistributedCacheManager.determineTimestamps(ClientDistributedCacheManager.java:93)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.filecache.ClientDistributedCacheManager.determineTimestampsAndCacheVisibilities(ClientDistributedCacheManager.java:57)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter.copyAndConfigureFiles(JobSubmitter.java:269)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter.copyAndConfigureFiles(JobSubmitter.java:390)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter.submitJobInternal(JobSubmitter.java:483)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job$10.run(Job.java:1296)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job$10.run(Job.java:1293)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1628)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.submit(Job.java:1293)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient$1.run(JobClient.java:562)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient$1.run(JobClient.java:557)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1628)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.submitJobInternal(JobClient.java:557)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.submitJob(JobClient.java:548)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.mr.ExecDriver.execute(ExecDriver.java:420)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.mr.ExecDriver.main(ExecDriver.java:740)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:221)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:136)
Job Submission failed with exception 'java.io.FileNotFoundException(File does not exist: hdfs://172.16.253.17:54310/home/hadoop/mapreduce/HoursDiff.jar)'
Execution failed with exit status: 1
```

Comment: please add the whole exception stack-trace to your question (edit)

Comment: just post the whole error message. it should be multiple lines, and also tell you which file is not found.

Comment: please find description above...

Comment: uups.. someone removed your stack trace... please add it again. (btw, i did not see FileNotFoundException there.. is there an other one?)

Comment: please check it now..

Comment: now it looks like a good question, thanks for keeping on it! :-) i can;t help you, but i am sure someone will come along soon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Everything you done is correct, but it is searching in HDFS path, you registered with local path.

Copy the jar into **HDFS location** and try to register it with the HDFS path.

I hope you opened the **hive** terminal with HDFS user, so it is searching the path of HDFS.

**Note:** It will also accept the local path also to register the jar.

Comment: could you please let me know how to change the uri as its looking hdfs.
yes i have logged into hadoop user only.

Comment: thank you so much durga.. its working fine as i created same direcotry in hdfs. 
could you please let me know how to change the uri as its looking hdfs.
yes i have logged into hadoop user only.

Comment: Login as normal Linux user, and open hive prompt. Then you will be able to add the jar using local home path.             If you want to run it throgh hue or any hadoop user, then you need to copy the jar to HDFS location as  it will point to HDFS location only.

Comment: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33014111/how-to-do-partitions-on-subdirectories-in-hive/33015059#33015059) can you please look into this link its been big problem for me please...boss